# How to resolve MaxRetiresError on AWS Elastic Beanstalk CLI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

So I am trying to deploy a django application and trying to initialize my eb cli repository with the `eb init` command, but I am getting an error when running this command:

`eb init -p python-3.9 django-tutorial`

```
ERROR: MaxRetriesError - Max retries exceed for ResponseParserErrorUnable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
B’’
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
```

Also, it looks like when I just run `eb init`, I am getting the same error as well. Not sure what went wrong. I am using git bash, a windows machine, django 3.1, and python 3.9.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:
I did run the `eb init -v` command and I receive the same error:

Code:

```
eb init -v
```

Output:

```
Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5) eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6) ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7) ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8) ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9) ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10) ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11) sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12) cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13) cn-northwest-1 : China (Ningxia)
14) us-east-2 : US East (Ohio)
15) ca-central-1 : Canada (Central)
16) eu-west-2 : EU (London)
17) eu-west-3 : EU (Paris)
18) eu-north-1 : EU (Stockholm)
19) eu-south-1 : EU (Milano)
20) ap-east-1 : Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)
21) me-south-1 : Middle East (Bahrain)
22) af-south-1 : Africa (Cape Town)
(default is 3): 1

ERROR: MaxRetriesError - Max retries exceeded for ResponseParserErrorsUnable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
Unable to parse response (no element found: line 1, column 0), invalid XML received. Further retries may succeed:
b''
```

Comment: Try `eb init -v` for verbose mode which may give more hints - can you please then add the output to the question?

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, I ran that command and still receive the same error as above.

Comment: Please add the exact full output and input

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary, I put it under my edit section.

Comment: Okay thank you - reinstall the AWS EB CLI

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be stuck in this issue, the solution is to go to `~/%USERNAME%/.aws` and delete the 'config' file there, then try running `eb init` again.

Answer (score 0):

So seems like you have successfully installed aws ebcli  but you are not able to run `eb init` command.
This happened with me also, the solution is simple **you need to configure aws ebcli before running `eb init`**

1:- For doing so firstly refer this article and create and set up ebcli
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/set-up-command-line-elastic-beanstalk/

2:- **copy the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key  as we will be needing it further**

3:- Now in your cli run `aws configure` and fill in the AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key that you copied previously and now your aws ebcli is successfully configured .

congratulations now you can run `eb init` command.